# Convert a string to a formatted array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to convert a serialized string into an array

This is the string i'm getting on php (form sent using serialized AJAX POST)

```
"ref_1=000CBA0000&name_1=Produto%20A&quantity_1=1&ref_2=000CBA0000&name_2=Produto%20A&quantity_2=1&ref_3=000CBA0000&name_3=Produto%20A&quantity_3=1"
```

every product that comes in the string have it's own ref,name,quantity, so currently my string comes with the information of 3 products, it may change every request.

I'm trying to convert the serialized string to an array with this format

```
[
    [1]
        ref => <copy the value from ref_1>
        name => <copy the value from name_1>
        quantity => <copy the value from quantity_1>
    [2]
        ref => <copy the value from ref_2>
        name => <copy the value from name_2>
        quantity => <copy the value from quantity_2>

    [3] 
        ref => <copy the value from ref_3>
        name => <copy the value from name_3>
        quantity => <copy the value from quantity_3>
]
```

So later i can do a **foreach** product and fetch them individually.

i tried exploding the string with:

```
$array = explode("&",$string);
var_dump($array);
```

but that gives me a different result:

```
array(9) { [0]=> string(16) "ref_1=000CBA0000" [1]=> string(21) "name_1=Produto%20A" [2]=> string(12) "quantity_1=1" [3]=> string(16) "ref_2=000CBA0000" [4]=> string(21) "name_2=Produto%20A" [5]=> string(12) "quantity_2=1" [6]=> string(16) "ref_3=000CBA0000" [7]=> string(21) "name_3=Produto%20A" [8]=> string(12) "quantity_3=1" }
```

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: It looks like a GET url. Where does this string come from? You don't need the `name` parameter?

Comment: ajax serialize() sent via POST , sorry i had product in it but it's name, fixed it.Thanks for the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the parameters then loop over the array and [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode) the key to get the key name and key number separately.

```
parse_str("ref_1=000CBA0000&name_1=Produto%20A&quantity_1=1&ref_2=000CBA0000&name_2=Produto%20A&quantity_2=1&ref_3=000CBA0000&name_3=Produto%20A&quantity_3=1", $arr);


foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $temp = explode("_", $key);
    $new[$temp[1]][$temp[0]] = $val;
}
var_dump($new);
```

Gives:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ref"]=>
    string(10) "000CBA0000"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Produto A"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ref"]=>
    string(10) "000CBA0000"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Produto A"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ref"]=>
    string(10) "000CBA0000"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Produto A"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/WVGiv

As Cid mentions, this will work as long as the keys have an underscore in the name separating the name and the number, in that order.
If it doesn't it will fail.

Comment: was about to post the same answer you've ben faster :)

Comment: As long as the answers are posted within resonable time then I'm fine with that. Maybe your answer have a better explanation

Comment: Too late, I discarded my answer hehe. I would add that this will work as long as **all** url parameters looks like `something_number`

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! Thanks! Marked!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code that will do what you asked and no matter how many params(and in what order) your string will have:

```
$string = "ref_1=000CBA0000&name_1=Produto%20A&quantity_1=1&ref_2=000CBA0000&name_2=Produto2%20A&quantity_2=2&ref_3=000CBA0000&name_3=Produt3o%20A&quantity_3=3";

parse_str($string, $paramsArray);

$result = [];

foreach ($paramsArray as $key => $item) {
    if (strpos($key, 'ref_') !== false) {
        $itemNumber = substr($key, strpos($key, "ref_") - 1);
        $result[] = [
          'ref' => $key,
          'name' =>  $paramsArray['name_'.$itemNumber],
          'quantity' =>  $paramsArray['quantity_'.$itemNumber],
        ];

    }
}
```

in result you will have needed format:

```
[
    [1]
        ref => <copy the value from ref_1>
        name => <copy the value from name_1>
        quantity => <copy the value from quantity_1>
    [2]
        ref => <copy the value from ref_2>
        name => <copy the value from name_2>
        quantity => <copy the value from quantity_2>

    [3] 
        ref => <copy the value from ref_3>
        name => <copy the value from name_3>
        quantity => <copy the value from quantity_3>
]
```